# Changing cell data

Tags: php, grid, radphp, rpcl

For a project I need to work in RadPHP XE2

In this project I created a DBGRid.

This is all working fine.

Now I need to change the cell color for each cell.

The color for the cell is depending on the value inside that cell.

Like this:

if value > 0 
  return green
else
  return red

Answer (score 0):

Well here is the PHP code for what you need. =) Don't really understand your question all that well though.

```
if( $value > 0 ){

    return "red";

}else{
    return "green";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add the color changing code in OnBeforeShow event of the dbgrid component.